# Fresh generated app in react-native crashes when installed directly from an IPA file through iTunes

Tags: react-native

Apple rejected my react native app.

In the following steps they advised to generate an ad-hoc IPA file and install it trough iTunes. Doing this the app actually crashed, though through XCode I can never replicate the issue.

I tried to initialise a fresh React Native App, generate the ad-hoc IPA file and install it through iTunes. The app just crashes  when I launch it and the device log is the following:

```
Incident Identifier: 36E07E1C-8C01-49F8-B46C-B24928E063A7
CrashReporter Key:   86805613c6d8d27a1e57d4bec9db2d9c4d379174
Hardware Model:      iPad2,2
Process:             teste3 [296]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/74D5C010-B091-4D55-8502-0DE008F3F6F5/teste3.app/teste3
Identifier:          org.reactjs.native.example.teste3
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-02-18 12:46:36.36 +0000
Launch Time:         2016-02-18 12:46:35.35 +0000
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x22544106 __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x21ceae12 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2254404c +[NSException raise:format:] + 108
3   teste3                          0x000e849e 0xd2000 + 91294
4   teste3                          0x000ffc48 0xd2000 + 187464
5   teste3                          0x000fdbd4 0xd2000 + 179156
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x220bdb56 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x220bdb42 _dispatch_client_callout + 18
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x220cbedc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1520
9   CoreFoundation                  0x225073f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 4
10  CoreFoundation                  0x225058f2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1570
11  CoreFoundation                  0x22458bf4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
12  CoreFoundation                  0x224589e0 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
13  GraphicsServices                0x236a4ac4 GSEventRunModal + 156
14  UIKit                           0x266e8b9c UIApplicationMain + 140
15  teste3                          0x000d72be 0xd2000 + 21182
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x2210786e tlv_get_addr + 42


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221d8c84 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227e732 pthread_kill + 62
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x2216f0ac abort + 108
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x21cc6ae4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x21cdf69e default_terminate_handler() + 266
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x21ceb0b0 _objc_terminate() + 192
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x21cdce16 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x21cdc5f4 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x21ceaeea objc_exception_throw + 250
9   CoreFoundation                  0x22544050 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
10  teste3                          0x000e84a2 0xd2000 + 91298
11  teste3                          0x000ffc4c 0xd2000 + 187468
12  teste3                          0x000fdbd8 0xd2000 + 179160
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x220bdb5a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x220bdb46 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x220cbee0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1524
16  CoreFoundation                  0x225073fc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
17  CoreFoundation                  0x225058f6 __CFRunLoopRun + 1574
18  CoreFoundation                  0x22458bf8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
19  CoreFoundation                  0x224589e4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
20  GraphicsServices                0x236a4ac8 GSEventRunModal + 160
21  UIKit                           0x266e8ba0 UIApplicationMain + 144
22  teste3                          0x000d72c2 0xd2000 + 21186
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x22107872 start + 2

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221da320 kevent_qos + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x220d2098 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 256
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x220d1df6 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 38

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221d988c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227bb34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227b718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221d988c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227bb34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227b718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221d988c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227bb34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227b718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221d988c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227bb34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227b718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221d988c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227bb34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227b718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221d9024 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x2212eeec nanosleep + 172
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x21cbf8b8 std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > const&) + 136
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x255a52fc bmalloc::waitUntilFalse(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1ll, 1000ll> >, bool&) + 188
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x255a510c bmalloc::Heap::scavenge(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1ll, 1000ll> >) + 36
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x255a4faa bmalloc::Heap::concurrentScavenge() + 78
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x255a6b06 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::entryPoint() + 98
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x255a6aa0 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::pthreadEntryPoint(void*) + 8
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227d85a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227d7ce _pthread_start + 110
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227b724 thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221c4c24 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x221c4a28 mach_msg + 40
2   CoreFoundation                  0x22507354 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
3   CoreFoundation                  0x225056dc __CFRunLoopRun + 1036
4   CoreFoundation                  0x22458bf8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x224589e4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
6   CFNetwork                       0x22a9b81e +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 486
7   Foundation                      0x22d5d164 __NSThread__start__ + 1148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227d85a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227d7ce _pthread_start + 110
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2227b724 thread_start + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x38d75000      r6: 0x37fb7314      r7: 0x00293f18
    r8: 0x14e83f40    r9: 0x21ce08fd     r10: 0x14e639e0     r11: 0x14e83f64
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x00293f0c      lr: 0x2227e733      pc: 0x221d8c84
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0xd2000 - 0x165fff teste3 armv7  <96f080f1f4c43413acafa80bb29522aa> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/74D5C010-B091-4D55-8502-0DE008F3F6F5/teste3.app/teste3
0x1fede000 - 0x1ff05fff dyld armv7  <d26f80447...
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you follow the official "Building your app for production" [guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#building-your-app-for-production)?